# datepicker - How to set correct selection in onChangeMonthYear

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker

i have this datepicker and the function onChangeMonthYear, but the problem is the month are 12-1 when selected. 
how can i change it?
thanks

```
$("#monthPicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'MM/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: false,
            //showAnim: "slideDown",


            onChangeMonthYear: function (dateText, inst) {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                //minDate: new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
                //maxDate: new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
                $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('MM/yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));
                //$(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                $(this).datepicker('refresh');


            }
        });
```

Comment: correct selection means what ? do you want to change display format ?

Comment: @MannanBahelim No. Its when i put for ex June in selection, in the textbox it shows May. Month -1

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="line col-sm-3">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Month picker</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control monthpicker input-sm" >
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
             $(".monthpicker").datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                minViewMode: 1,
                format: 'MM'
            }).on('changeDate', function(selected){
                    startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
                    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
                    $('.monthpicker').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
                });
    });
</script>
```